# DejaGNU - want to use environment variable from Linux throughout tests

Tags: linux, testing, environment-variables

I have some existing DejaGNU tests I need to modify, I want to replace some hard coded /dev entries with an environment variable, e.g. instead of /dev/ttyS0 I want /dev/$PORT where PORT is defined in the parent Linux shell.

How do I get a variable from the parent shell into DejaGNU?

Answer (score 1):

$env(PORT)

If you want to test whether the environment variable is set, you can use

[info exists env(PORT)]